# Get the index of the nth item of a type in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that can look something like this:

```
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]
```

I would like to get the n-th `-` and return everything after it. So I tried this, and at first I thought that it was working, but then as I look at it I see that it is getting the index then pulling from that index in the array not the index of the dash.

So for example if `n` is equal to 4 it currently is getting the 4th index, and not the fourth dash which is at index 10.

```js
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]

// Get the number of dashes
let stops = items.filter(i => i == '-').length
// Select a random dash
let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * stops)
// find the dash at the random position, then get a list of items that are not a dash
let sel = items.slice(n + 1).filter(r => r != '-')
// Select the first 3 items for the final output
let final = sel.slice(0, 3)

console.log(n)
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. The comments in the code describe.

```js
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]


let stops = [];

// Push dashes indexes according to the `items` into the `stops`.
items.forEach((item, index) => item === '-' ? stops.push(index) : false); // false is done only for one line body
console.log(stops);

// Select a random dash
let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * stops.length);
console.log(n);

// find the dash at the random position and use that position to get from the `stops` array and use that value according to the `items`, then get a list of items that are not a dash
let sel = items.slice(stops[n] + 1).filter(r => r !== '-');

// Select the first 3 items for the final output
let final = sel.slice(0, 3);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a the wanted number for decrementing and return `true` if the counter reaches zero.

```js
const
    items = [1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45],
    getNth = n => items.slice(items.findIndex(v => v === '-' && !--n) + 1);

console.log(getNth(1));
console.log(getNth(2));
console.log(getNth(3));
console.log(getNth(4));
console.log(getNth(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `findIndex()` with `slice()` for this.

```js
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]

function getNth(data, n) {
  let c = 0;
  let i = data.findIndex(e => e == '-' && ++c == n ? true : false);
  return i != -1 ? data.slice(i + 1) : undefined;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getNth(items, 2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNth(items, 1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNth(items, 4)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNth(items, 100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]
function getNth(value){
  var count = 0;
  var myIndex;
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
   if(item === "-"){
    count++;
    if(count === value ){
      myIndex = index;
    }
  }
  })

  return items.slice(myIndex);
}

console.log(getNth(2))
console.log(getNth(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let items = [
  1, '-', 231, '-', 6, 67, '-', 13, 177, 451, '-', 43, '-', 345, 56, 45
]
let n = 3 // nth item
let count = 0
let index
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 if(items[i] == '-') {
  count++
    }
 if(count == n) {
  index = i + 1
  break;
    }
}
let final = items.slice(index, items.length + 1)
console.log(JSON.stringify(final))
```